# is there a way to work offline with vscode remote ssh to save cost?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtual-machine, vscode-remote

I am using vscode ssh remote plugin https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

to connect to gcp sandbox vm. gcp sandbox vm has an hourly cost if kept turned on.

most of the time I am reading or changing the code and I am not running any command in the VM's terminal. So, if I had the code offline, I would not need to keep the VM running and pay for each second of it.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: what are the possibilities to upload files to the gcp sandbox

Answer (score 1):

When using VSCode over SSH, you are running a VSCode server on the remote host which is used to read the files.

If you want to be able to open files locally, you will need to download them.

If you already have the files opened, you can disconnect from the VM and keep looking at them.

Another option to consider is mounting whatever file store you're using locally as a FUSE file system. Here is an example for git: https://github.com/presslabs/gitfs